# What determines the signs of the trigonometric functions in the quadrants of the xy-plane?

Tags: trigonometry

In the *xy*-plane, how can we determine the signs of the trigonometric functions in each quadrant? For example, sine is positive in Quadrant I, cosine is negative in Quadrant II, etc. How can we determine this?

Comment: You already asked this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1863177/409). (It was closed, but now has three reopen votes (including one from me), so there's hope.) Re-posting a question is not the appropriate way to respond to close votes.

Comment: @Blue: Unfortunately, it looks like it never got reopened, and instead was deleted by the roomba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a circle of radius $1$ centred at the origin[image]

The coordinates on any point of this circle are given by $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle shown.

This should give an easy way of determining what sign goes where.

Comment: This is not "an easy way of determining". Rather, this is the **correct** way of **defining** $\cos,\sin$ geometrically.